# Why can't I declare a data member from another class private within my class definition

Tags: c++, c++11

I am getting a compiler error saying that the data member Point p is private within the context, when I declare Point p as private within class circle. The code and compiler error are below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
 class Point
 {
   public:
   Point(double a, double b)
{
    x = a;
    y = b;
   
}
   virtual ~Point(){}
   private:
   double x;
   double y;
};
```

The code for the class shape and circle are as follows:

```
class shapes {
         public:
         virtual Point centre() const = 0;
         virtual void draw() const = 0;
         virtual void rotate(int angle) const = 0;
         virtual ~shapes(){}
 };

class circle: public shapes {
        public:
         Point centre() const override { return p; }
         void draw() const override { }
         void rotate(int angle) const override {}
         virtual ~circle() {}
         circle(Point x, int r):p{x},radius{r}{}
       
         private:
          Point p;
          int radius; };
```

Edit: Smiley face class inherits from circle class with code below:

```
class smiley: public circle
{ //smiley face is a circle + eyes and mouth
public:
smiley(Point p, int r):circle{p,r},mouth{nullptr}{}
Point centre() const override { return p;}
void draw() const override 
{
    //draw circle
    circle::draw();
    for(auto e:eyes)
    {
        e->draw();
    }
    mouth->draw();

}
void rotate(int angle) const {}

virtual ~smiley()
{
    delete mouth;
    for (auto eye : eyes) //why not delete [] eyes
    {
        delete eye;
    }
}
private:
std::vector<shapes*> eyes; //smiley face has eyes
shapes* mouth; //smiley face has a mouth
};
```

If I make the data member p public in the class circle, everything works. The compiler error is listed below:
[image]

Why can I not define the Point object p, in the circle class private?

**Edit: I have added the compiler error message and added the missing code asked for in the comments below. Would you be able to re-open the question?**

Comment: Please provide the exact code and location of the error, as displayed by the compiler. There are a lot of details missing here.

Comment: The problem must be in code you're not showing.

Comment: The code you have shown would not exhibit the symptom you describe.    The code you have posted, almost certainly, differs from your actual code presumably because (1)  you have deemed some aspects of your actual code irrelevant, but they actually are relevant   and (2)  you have not tested to see if the code you have posted still exhibits the same concern.    That forces people to guess what your actual problem is.    To reduce chances of others having to guess, read up on how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: *"... within this context"*  What context?  What **exact** (verbatim) error message?

Comment: Off-topic, but don't use plural names, like "shapes", for singular things. You will make your later self very confused.

Comment: @Peter yes you are right. I have added the remaining code. Thanks.

Comment: @Eljay Have added a screenshot of the error message.

Comment: A `private` member of a base class is inaccessible to any derived class (unless a derived class is declared as `friend`, which is not a good idea).   In your case, `p` is a `private` member of `circle`, so is inaccessible to `smiley`.    Options to fix include (1) make `centre()` non-virtual in `circle`, so it is not necessary for `smiley` to override it (and not necessary to access `p` to do so)  (2) have `smiley::centre()` simply call `circle::centre()` (which is accessible since it is `public`).   I would lean to the first.

Comment: Remove the `smiley::centre()` override - it's is not needed because it's already overridden by `circle` in the inheritance tree.

Comment: I have voted to reopen.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance)

Comment: @Peter Thanks Peter, yes this answers the question. Thanks for highlighting the different solutions and the relative merits of each. Very helpful - if you think its worthwhile to others as well, then do post it as an answer and will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Private class members can only be accessed within the class or by friends, so, if you would like it to be accessed outside the class by a non-friend, you would need to use a setter/getter.

Comment: This exact code, without trying to access p from outside the class, does not produce an error and it shouldn't.